# Continuous anchor face restrictions do not work in jsPlumb 1.7.5

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I want to build graphs that have a general direction from top to bottom. That is why I want to restrict any connections to be painted coming from the *bottom face of any source* and going into the *top face of any target*, preferrably `Continuous` (as a matter of fact, trying to create `Static` or `Dynamic` anchors actually throws an error telling me that those types don't exist). It appears that [the documentation](http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/anchors.html#continuous) is a bit out of date?

I followed the instructions and made sure to call the following code on all my graph nodes (`$element`):

```
plumbInstance.makeSource($element, {
    anchor:['Continuous', { faces:[ "bottom" ] } ]
});

plumbInstance.makeTarget($element, {
    anchor:['Continuous', { faces:[ "top" ] } ]
});
```

But it simply ignores these restrictions and still chooses the closest face, rather than only top and bottom faces.

NOTE: I am using [jsPlumb version 1.7.5](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/js/dom.jsPlumb-1.7.5.js).

What am I doing wrong?